# Configure caption on listings environment using multicol (latex)

Tags: latex, listings

I want to make a dual column code in latex but with the caption above the two columns. Ex:

```
  Program 1 : some text here for the caption

1   //col 1              7    //col2
2   void main (void)     8   void foo(void)
3   {                    9   {
4      //just a test    10      int c;
5      return 0;        11      c = 0;
6   }                   12   }
```

I'm using **listings**. To accomplish the layout above, I cut in two listings inside one table. There are some problems with this approach, I have to manually divide the code and watch for the result in the PDF.

I'd like to use [multicol=2] option, but with this, the caption stack only on the first column. Does anyone now how to overcome (if possible?)

```
    Program 1 : some text 7    //col2
    here for the caption  8   void foo(void)
1   //col 1               9   {
2   void main (void)     10      int c;
3   {                    11      c = 0;
4      //just a test     12   }
5      return 0;         
6   }
```

Just below is the non working code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\lstset{
   language=C,
   breaklines=true,
   prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
}

\begin{lstlisting}[stepnumber=1,multicols=2,caption=Caption test to confirm that multicol does not like large captions]
void MudaDigito(char val)
{
   if (pos == 0)
   {
     v0 = val;
   }
   if (pos == 1)
   {
     v1 = val;
   }
   if (pos == 2)
   {
     v2 = val;
   }
   if (pos == 3)
   {
     v3 = val;
   }
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

\end{document}

Comment: Would it work if you could just add a title (maybe a section or just bold text) right before you display your listing? So it would be independent of the listings package.

Comment: @nEm: good suggestion, and an option in some cases, although then you don't get to use LaTeX's caption numbering facilities. I also experimented with including both a centered section and the caption and the results were underwhelming visually since the caption stayed in 2column format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same problem. I found a solution.
It's not clean but it works. 
Just below is the working code.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand{\listingcaption}[1]%
{%
\refstepcounter{lstlisting}\hfill%
Listing \thelstlisting -- #1\hfill%\hfill%
}%
\begin{document}
\lstset{
   language=C,
   breaklines=true,
   prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
}
\listingcaption{Caption test to confirm that multicol does not like large captions\label{list1}}
\begin{lstlisting}[stepnumber=1,multicols=2]
void MudaDigito(char val)
{
   if (pos == 0)
   {
     v0 = val;
   }
   if (pos == 1)
   {
     v1 = val;
   }
   if (pos == 2)
   {
     v2 = val;
   }
   if (pos == 3)
   {
     v3 = val;
   }
}
\end{lstlisting}
See listing \ref{list1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: that the resulting captions do not appear in the table of listings. (At least not if using classicthesis)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The caption is shown in the text and not with the listing itself. I want the listing to be shown as float=t.